# Order_id is invalid in Paytm Integration in iOS swift4

Tags: swift4, paytm

Paytm Integration in swift4: 
The response is **Transaction Finished** and the response message is **Invalid order id**  but I'm generating order id new at every transaction, is there any possible solution for this. 
Parameter which I'm passing :

```
    var orderID = "123456789".randomString(length: 20)
    orderDict["MID"] = "RentSe98692194807190"
    orderDict["CHANNEL_ID"] = "WAP"
    orderDict["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = "Retail"
    orderDict["WEBSITE"] = "APP_STAGING"
    orderDict["TXN_AMOUNT"] = "100"
    orderDict["ORDER_ID"] = orderID
    orderDict["CHECKSUMHASH"] = checksumHash
    orderDict["CUST_ID"] = "240"
    orderDict["EMAIL"] = "kj@gmail.com" as AnyObject
    orderDict["MOBILE_NO"] = "7777777777" as AnyObject
    orderDict["REQUEST_TYPE"] = "DEFAULT" as AnyObject
    orderDict["THEME"] = "merchant" as AnyObject
    orderDict["CALLBACK_URL"] = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp" as AnyObject
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //MARK:- Create Payment

func createPayment(checksumHash : String, orderID : String) {

    var custID = ""
    var orderID = String()

    custID =  custID.randomString(length: 20)
    print(custID)

    var orderDict = [AnyHashable : Any]()

    let txnAmt = ((self.amountTextField.text) ?? "0")
    print(txnAmt)

    orderDict["MID"] = "RentSe98692194807190"
    orderDict["CHANNEL_ID"] = "WAP"
    orderDict["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = "Retail"
    orderDict["WEBSITE"] = "APP_STAGING"
    orderDict["TXN_AMOUNT"] = txnAmt as AnyObject
    orderDict["ORDER_ID"] = orderID
    orderDict["CHECKSUMHASH"] = checksumHash
    orderDict["CUST_ID"] = custID
    orderDict["EMAIL"] = "kj@gmail.com" as AnyObject
    orderDict["MOBILE_NO"] = "7777777777" as AnyObject
    orderDict["REQUEST_TYPE"] = "DEFAULT" as AnyObject
    orderDict["THEME"] = "merchant" as AnyObject
    orderDict["CALLBACK_URL"] = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp" as AnyObject

    print(custID)
    let pgOrder = PGOrder(params: orderDict)

    let transaction = PGTransactionViewController.init(transactionFor: pgOrder)
    if eServerTypeStaging != eServerTypeNone {

        transaction!.serverType = eServerTypeStaging
        transaction!.merchant = merchant
        transaction!.delegate = self
        self.present(transaction!, animated: true, completion: {

        })
    }
}`
```

Comment: I have similar issue as getting invalid ORDER ID. Transaction is success from the app side and then to verify transaction same order id is passed to my own server from where they called verify url of paytm and gets error as invalid order id why?
Thank you!

Comment: Because orderId we need to generate unique every time .
 let orderID = "".randomString(length: 20)

Comment: Please check this for once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55804117/paytm-console-giving-404-error-in-swift-4/55804626#55804626