# Paytm console giving 404 error in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, paytm

I'm implementing Paytm in iOS using Swift 4. I'm sending requested data to paytm console, but it is showing "404 Not Found" error.
I'm sending the following data to paytm:

```
let merchantConfig = PGMerchantConfiguration.default()
merchantConfig?.checksumGenerationURL = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCheckSumGenerator.jsp" 
merchantConfig?.checksumValidationURL = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCheckSumVerify.jsp" 

let odrDict = NSMutableDictionary()

odrDict["CALLBACK_URL"] = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp",
odrDict["CHANNEL_ID"] = "WAP",
odrDict["CUST_ID"] =  "30244",
odrDict["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = "Software",
odrDict["MID"] = self.MID
odrDict["ORDER_ID"] = "29",
odrDict["REQUEST_TYPE"] = "DEFAULT",
odrDict["TXN_AMOUNT"] = "200",
odrDict["WEBSITE"] = "WEB_STAGING"
odrDict["CHECKSUMHASH"] = "a/4w+QPWAEZXlNXg48Nr9OQoBYGDjj1lVbY4VPhAqi4pkadfcUFoY6UToaHNnND8pNoDCJRxYlFEirdsnowwMACKAXgTB3ScBBYorzipqQ=",
odrDict["MOBILE_NO"] = "7777777777"
odrDict["EMAIL"] = "demo@gmail.com"

print("odrDict",odrDict)

let order: PGOrder = PGOrder(params: odrDict as? [AnyHashable : Any])
let transactionController = PGTransactionViewController(transactionFor: order)
transactionController?.serverType = eServerTypeStaging
transactionController?.merchant = merchantConfig
transactionController?.delegate = self
self.showController(controller: transactionController!)
```

I don't know, what I'm doing wrong. Every time I request to open the paytm console, it is giving 404 not found.

Comment: Please check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471895/order-id-is-invalid-in-paytm-integration-in-ios-swift4 May be it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

```
     extension ABViewController: UIViewController {

        var custID = ""
        override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.setMerchant()


        custID =  custID.randomString(length: 20)
        print(custID)
      }

        func setMerchant() {


            merchant  = PGMerchantConfiguration.default()
            //user your checksum urls here or connect to paytm developer team for this or use default urls of paytm


            merchant.checksumGenerationURL = "http://test/Admin/paytm/generateChecksum.php";
            merchant.checksumValidationURL = "http://test/Admin/paytm/verifyChecksum.php";
        merchant.merchantID = "testI93673659336118";//paste here your merchant id  //mandatory
            merchant.website = "APPPROD";//mandatory
            merchant.industryID = "Retail109";//mandatory
            merchant.channelID = "WAP"; //provided by PG WAP //mandatory

            merchant.clientSSLCertPath = nil; //[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Certificate" ofType:@"p12"];
            merchant.clientSSLCertPassword = nil; //@"password";
        }

        //MARK:- Create Payment
        func createPayment(checksumHash : String, orderID : String) {

            var orderDict = [AnyHashable : Any]()

            let txnAmt = self.amountTextField.text!
            print(txnAmt)

            orderDict["MID"] = "RentSe98692194807190"
            orderDict["CHANNEL_ID"] = "WAP"
            orderDict["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = "Retail109"
            orderDict["WEBSITE"] = "APPPROD"
            orderDict["TXN_AMOUNT"] = "50" as AnyObject
            orderDict["ORDER_ID"] = orderID
            orderDict["CHECKSUMHASH"] = checksumHash
            orderDict["CUST_ID"] = custID
            orderDict["EMAIL"] = "kj@gmail.com" as AnyObject
            orderDict["MOBILE_NO"] = "7777777777" as AnyObject
            orderDict["REQUEST_TYPE"] = "DEFAULT" as AnyObject
            orderDict["THEME"] = "merchant" as AnyObject
            orderDict["CALLBACK_URL"] = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp" as AnyObject

            print(custID)
            let pgOrder = PGOrder(params: orderDict)

            let transaction = PGTransactionViewController.init(transactionFor: pgOrder)

            if eServerTypeStaging != eServerTypeNone {
                transaction!.serverType = eServerTypeProduction
                transaction!.merchant = merchant
                transaction!.delegate = self
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(transaction!, animated: true)
            }
        }

        func validatePaytm(checksumHash : String, orderID: String) {

            var orderDict = [String : AnyObject]()

            orderDict["CHECKSUMHASH"] = checksumHash as AnyObject
            orderDict["ORDER_ID"] = orderID as AnyObject
        }

        //MARK:- Generate Checksum from our Server
        func paytmAPI() {

            let url = "http://mstoo.co.in/Admin/paytm/generateChecksum.php"

            let orderID = "".randomString(length: 20)
            print(orderID)

            let txnAmt = self.amountTextField.text!
            print(txnAmt)

            var orderDict = [String : AnyObject]()

            orderDict["MID"] = "RentSe98692194807190" as AnyObject
            orderDict["CHANNEL_ID"] = "WAP" as AnyObject
            orderDict["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = "Retail109" as AnyObject
            orderDict["WEBSITE"] = "APPPROD" as AnyObject
            orderDict["TXN_AMOUNT"] = txnAmt as AnyObject
            orderDict["ORDER_ID"] = orderID as AnyObject
            orderDict["CUST_ID"] = custID as AnyObject
            orderDict["EMAIL"] = "kj@gmail.com" as AnyObject
            orderDict["MOBILE_NO"] = "7777777777" as AnyObject
            orderDict["REQUEST_TYPE"] = "DEFAULT" as AnyObject
            orderDict["THEME"] = "merchant" as AnyObject
            orderDict["CALLBACK_URL"] = "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp" as AnyObject

            let imageArray = [UIImage]()

            Methods.sharedInstance.showLoader(object: self.view)

            WebServiceClass.uploadeImageToServer(urlName: url, params: orderDict, uploadedImage: imageArray, imageName: "") { (isTrue, response, errorMessage) in

                Methods.sharedInstance.hideLoader(object: self.view)

                if let jsonResult = response as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    print(jsonResult)

                    self.paytmValidate(checksumhash: jsonResult["CHECKSUMHASH"] as? String ?? "", orderID: jsonResult["ORDER_ID"] as? String ?? "")
                } else {

                    self.showAlertWithoutCallBack(messageTitle: "MessageWhatHappen")
                }
            }
        }

        func paytmValidate(checksumhash: String,orderID: String) {

            let url = "http://test/Admin/paytm/verifyChecksum.php"

            var orderDict = [String : AnyObject]()

            orderDict["CHECKSUMHASH"] = checksumhash as AnyObject
            orderDict["ORDER_ID"] = orderID as AnyObject

            let imageArray = [UIImage]()

            WebServiceClass.uploadeImageToServer(urlName: url, params: orderDict, uploadedImage: imageArray, imageName: "") { (isTrue, response, errorMessage) in

                if let jsonResult = response as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    print(jsonResult)

                    self.createPayment(checksumHash:checksumhash, orderID:orderID)
                } else {

                     print("MessageWhatHappen")
                }
            }
        }
    }

   extension ABViewController:  PGTransactionDelegate {

        func didFinishedResponse(_ controller: PGTransactionViewController!, response responseString: String!) {

            print("Transaction Finished")
            print(responseString)
            let Str = responseString
            let finalDictResponse = convertToDictionary(text: Str ?? "")
            print(finalDictResponse)
            if let myDict = finalDictResponse as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>? {
                self.addMoneyAPI(transectionID : myDict["TXNID"] as? String ?? "")
                self.removeController(controller: controller)
                showToast(message: "Finish Response")

            }
        }

        func didCancelTrasaction(_ controller: PGTransactionViewController!) {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            self.showToast(message: "Transaction Cancelled")
        }

        func errorMisssingParameter(_ controller: PGTransactionViewController!, error: Error!) {

            self.removeController(controller: controller)
            showToast(message: "Missing Parameters")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.removeController(controller: controller)
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
            showAlert(title: "didCancelTrasaction", message: error.localizedDescription)
        }

        func didSucceedTransaction(_ controller: PGTransactionViewController!, response: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {

            print(response)
            self.showToast(message: "Transaction Successful")

        }

        func didFailTransaction(_ controller: PGTransactionViewController!, error: Error!, response: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {

            print(error)
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
            self.showToast(message: "Transaction Failed")
        }

        func didFinishCASTransaction(_ controller: PGTransactionViewController!, response: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {

            print(response)
        }

        func showController(controller: PGTransactionViewController) {

            if self.navigationController != nil {
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
            } else {
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
            }
        }

        func removeController(controller: PGTransactionViewController) {

            if self.navigationController != nil {
                print("Transcation Successful")

            } else {
                print("Transcation Successful")
            }
        }
    }
```